# finding the length of the longest subsequence

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, substring, sequence

Here, in this piece of code, it prints the length of the largest subsequence of a sequence that's increasing then decreasing or vice versa.

for example:

Input: 1, 11, 2, 10, 4, 5, 2, 1

Output: 6 (A Longest Subsequence of length 6 is 1, 2, 10, 4, 2, 1)

but how can I make it work with three monotonic (increasing or decreasing) regions?

like increasing-decreasing-increasing OR decreasing-increasing-decreasing

example:

input: 7 16 1 6 20 17 7 18 25 1 25 21 11 5 29 11 3 3 26 19

output: 12

(largest subsequence: 7 1 6 17 18 25 25 21 11 5 3 3) as we see,

it can be split into three regions:
7,1 / 6,17,18,25,25 / 21,11,5,3,3

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
def lbs(arr): 
    n = len(arr) 

    lis = [1 for i in range(n+1)] 

    for i in range(1 , n): 
        for j in range(0 , i): 
            if ((arr[i] > arr[j]) and (lis[i] < lis[j] +1)): 
                lis[i] = lis[j] + 1


    lds = [1 for i in range(n+1)] 

    for i in reversed(range(n-1)):
        for j in reversed(range(i-1 ,n)):  
            if(arr[i] > arr[j] and lds[i] < lds[j] + 1): 
                lds[i] = lds[j] + 1 



    maximum = lis[0] + lds[0] - 1
    for i in range(1 , n): 
        maximum = max((lis[i] + lds[i]-1), maximum) 

    return maximum 

print ("Length of LBS is",lbs(arr))
```

Comment: I don't think your approach is consistent with the statements you are making.  You say that you are looking for a subsequence, which usually implies an integral subsequence.  You are skipping values.  Further in your second portion mentions "monotonic increasing/decreasing regions" and again you are skipping values which makes this incredibly complex.  For instance, following your approach of skipping values, an answer to your first input could be [1, 11], [10, 5, 2, 1].

Comment: @Jeff H, I don't actually agree with you. Subsequence is commonly used for not necessarily continuous segments (examples: LCS, LIS problems, etc.). However, word 'region' might be indeed troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

I've came up with a O(n^2 log n) idea.

You want to divide your whole segment into three parts: first one containing increasing subsequence, second one containing decreasing one and the last one containing again increasing one.

First of all, let's choose a sequence's prefix - the first part (O(n) possibilities). To minimize the amount of checked intervals, you can pick only prefixes which last element is in their longest increasing subsequence. (In other words, when choosing range [1, x], a_x should be in it's longest increasing subsequence)

Now you have similar problem to the one you've already solved - finding decreasing, then increasing subsequence (I'd use binary search instead of for loop you used, by the way). The only difference is that the decreasing subsequence must start from values smaller than the last element of chosen prefix (just ignore any larger or equal values) - you're able to do it in O(n log n).